# Unexplained memory leak -> _stack_chk_fail

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

When my app starts up, I get 1 or more 4.00KB memory leaks with the frame being _stack_chk_fail and the library libSystem.B.dylib. Any suggestions on what this could be would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This website - http://blog.freimann.org/archives/16-__stack_chk_fail-when-compiling-filo.html

suggests you add

```
-fno-stack-protector
```

to your compile options.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not seem that the link you reference is related to Cocoa/Objective-C

Comment: gcc is the compiler that objc uses to compile (just like C), and this is a flag that gcc accepts. 

Under Xcode > Project > Edit Project Settings > Build you should be able to find a field to add this flag for gcc.

Comment: Fair enough, but fo you have any idea what this flag means? I would not like to add something to the compile options without understanding why or what it does

Comment: according to http://www.trl.ibm.com/projects/security/ssp/

this flag disables the stack-smashing protector, which protects your program against a stack smashing attack. since i wasn't familiar with that term I looked it up:

from http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/sDefinition/0,,sid14_gci913633,00.html

"Stack smashing is causing a stack in a computer application or operating system to overflow." Which is very fitting for this website....

Comment: Anyway, I don't think your computer will explode if you turn this flag on, I'd give it a try (maybe just like a temporary fix?) and if it doesn't work, then I would check if your gcc needs updating/patches.